# how to find .mp3 file with zenity

Tags: bash, shell, audio, find, mp3

I wrote script about schedule reminder, and I wish i can play an audio that i choosen before. i mean on my program variabel ***sounds*** looking for file with .mp3, but it doesn't work.
help me please.
thanks

```
nama=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter your name:" --entry-text " ");

date=$(zenity --calendar --text "choose your event's day" --date-format=%Y-%m-%d);

 tang=$(zenity --forms --date-format=`date | awk ¥{print $1 $3,$2,$6}¦ `| time :`date | awk '{print $4}'` );

  nambah=$(zenity --forms --ok-label="Done" --cancel-label="Cancel" --height=100 \
--title "Time" \
--text "Input Time(format 24)" \
--add-entry "Input Hours:Minutes:Second");

sounds=$(find | *.mp3 | zenity --list --column "choose sounds");


text=$(zenity --text-info --title "create event" --editable --font=Purisa);

 a=1
 while (a==1)
 do

  cekdate="`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`";
  cektime="`date '+%H:%M:%S'`";
echo "echo cektime: $cektime"
echo "echo cekdate: $cekdate"
echo "nambah: $nambah"
echo "date: $date"
if [ "$nambah" == "$cektime" -a "$date" == "$cekdate" ]
then
 echo -n
d=`echo "Time: $nambah"`
break
 fi
done

 out=$(zenity --info --text "REMEMBER!! $nama today is $date you have event $d

 $text ");
```

Comment: That line: `sounds=$(find | *.mp3 | zenity --list --column "choose sounds");` is your problem right?  That is not how you use the find command to search for *.mp3 files...  Please confirm.

Comment: While I am here, FYI, you should read this: https://www.networkworld.com/article/2694433/unix-good-coding-practices-for-bash.html   and indent your code.  `;` is not required on each line.

Comment: Learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` . AND avoid the top 10 shell script beginner mistakes by reading https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info multiple times. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 places where you need to make change in your code:

1. Change the way you `find` the mp3 files:

   ```
   sounds=$(find <path_to_mp3_directory> -type f -name "*.mp3" | zenity --list --column "choose sounds")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^#this must be edited to your needs
   ```
2. Call your favorite mp3 player at the end of your code, if required you need to install it before hand. Check what is available on your platform and use your package manager to install it

   ```
   #play your music with your favorite player : mplayer, ffplay, nvlc, play (sox) or mpg123 (if you do not have the tools: sudo apt-get install mpg123/you favorite mp3 player)
   mplayer $sounds #mpg123 $sounds
   ```

**Your code become:**

```
nama=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter your name:" --entry-text " ")

date=$(zenity --calendar --text "choose your event's day" --date-format=%Y-%m-%d)

tang=$(zenity --forms --date-format=`date | awk \{print $1 $3,$2,$6}| `| time :`date | awk '{print $4}'` )

nambah=$(zenity --forms --ok-label="Done" --cancel-label="Cancel" --height=100 \
--title "Time" \
--text "Input Time(format 24)" \
--add-entry "Input Hours:Minutes:Second");

sounds=$(find <path_to_mp3_directory> -type f -name "*.mp3" | zenity --list --column "choose sounds")


text=$(zenity --text-info --title "create event" --editable --font=Purisa)

a=1
while (a==1)
do

    cekdate="`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`"
    cektime="`date '+%H:%M:%S'`"
    echo "echo cektime: $cektime"
    echo "echo cekdate: $cekdate"
    echo "nambah: $nambah"
    echo "date: $date"
    if [ "$nambah" == "$cektime" -a "$date" == "$cekdate" ]
    then
        echo -n
        d=`echo "Time: $nambah"`
    break
    fi
done

out=$(zenity --info --text "REMEMBER!! $nama today is $date you have event $d
$text ")
#play your music with your favorite player : mplayer, ffplay, nvlc, play (sox) or mpg123 (if you do not have the tools: sudo apt-get install mpg123/you favorite mp3 player)
mplayer $sounds # or mpg123 $sounds, etc.
```

Comment: big thanks again Allan, :)
thats helped me again.
honestly i'm the beginner